# Using fontawesome unicode with OpenLayers style?

Tags: openlayers

I want to style a feature with fontawesome icons. When I define unicode icon hardly, The style work correctly. But when I want to get unicode from a text field, It dosn't work. See the sample in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malvandi_m/uxea175c/).

```
const map = new ol.Map({
    ...
});

const textInput = document.getElementById('textinput');

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: feature.get('text') + ' => ' + textInput.value,
        font: '20px FontAwesome'
      })
    })
  }
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

const feature = new ol.Feature();
feature.set('text', '\uf0ac')
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
```

In generally, I want to save the unicode in db, and then get It and show. How can I use fontawesome with unicode in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the question myself. Use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(UnicodeString, 16))`. So the above code can be as follow:

```
feature.set('text', 'f0ac')
```

and the Style:

```
new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: String.fromCharCode(parseInt(feature.get('text'), 16)) + ' => ' + 
          String.fromCharCode(parseInt(textInput.value, 16)),
    font: '20px FontAwesome'
 })
```

Final sample code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/malvandi_m/yoLg3pv0/).

Comment: its work very code